# How to remove unnecessary background when a slide is active in the Slick-slider navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

With an active slide, a white background is displayed in the marker, which I set for inactive slides, how can I make it disappear on the active slide?

Code jsfiddle.net/mpvow81d/

Site ilyin1ib.beget.tech

[image]

```css
    .slick-dots li button {
        height: 4px !important;
        padding: 4px !important;
        width: 20px !important;
        background: #fff!important;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    li.slick-active {
        width: 40px !important;
        height:100% !important;
        background: @orange !important;
        z-index:99 !important;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }


    .slick-dots li button:before {
      display:none;
    }


    .slick-dots {
      bottom: 100px !important;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Comment: Sir if the question has got the correct answer then accepting the answer would be a great help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Respected developer,
The problem can be solved like this :

1. According to the way you want

```css
.slick-active button{
display:none;
}
```

2.correct or an easy way to do this.

```css
.slick-active button{
background:#ff5722 !important;
}
```

In the solution two rather than giving the styles to the active slick and making it a orange container you can just change the color of the white button inside the slick-active class to orange which makes your code small , easy and convenient.

suggestion: Upload your code in code pen or any other sites like repl i personally found difficulties in js fiddle.